# How to clear input in Vue multiselect?

Tags: vue.js

How do I clear the input entered in a Vue multiselect? I have this Vue multiselect, and I want to clear the search input (what's circled in yellow) when I select an item from the dropdown (circled in red). But I want to keep the input preserved until I change the dropdown selection (thus, I have clear-on-select set to false).

Here is my multiselect.

```
<vue-multiselect
        v-model="selected[generic]"
        :options="available[generic]"
        :multiple="true"
        :close-on-select="false"
        :clear-on-select="false"
        :show-labels="false"
        :preserve-search="true"
        :placeholder="description"
        label="name"
        :loading="targetsIsLoading"
        @search-change="inputEntered"
        track-by="uuid">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }">
        <span class="multiselect__single" v-if="available[generic].length && !isOpen">{{values.length}} options selected</span>
    </template>
</vue-multiselect>
```

[image]

Comment: The [MultiSelect documentation](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-multiple-select) I found seems to give you `:clear-on-select="true"` as a way to clear the search after selecting an option. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just reset the v-model `selected[generic] = undefined` when you select an option in your dropdown

Comment: @PeterKrebs - I do want to preserve the text entered in the input, so long as the dropdown under "Report By" does not change. It is when the Report By dropdown value changes that I'd like to remove the search input.

Comment: @Kapcash - I cannot do that because my selected values change depending on which Report By value I have selected. selected[generic] does not have anything to do with the input entered.

Comment: You can try with a dynamic value for `clear-on-select` like this: `:clear-on-select="!isOpen"`, does that work?